# See all the coordinates used in a turtle circle() drawing

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, turtle-graphics, cartesian-coordinates

I want to draw 1 DNA strand with its nitrogen bases: a litle piece of strand, one base, a litle pice of strand, another base, so on. In this order. 
But when you interrupt a `circle()`, (in this case a semicircle, the strand) to draw something else, like a straight line (that would be the base), the `circle()` angle is changed. And I can't think a way to change it back.

So, the easier way, make a semicircle, draw a line, and continue the semicircle, seems to be just `goto()` a cordinate and draw what you want there.

But to calculate all the precise coordinates of a circle, for each diferent circle, in case I need more, would be long.

There is any way to make turtle, or any other stuff/software, to return as output all the cordinates of a circle that I drew/coded?

Like, if I drew this `circle()`:

```
from turtle import *

t = Turtle()

t.seth(45)
t.circle(100,90)
t.circle(-100,90)
```

would it be possible for turtle to return the coordinates used to make it?

And here's an example of what I mean by create a circle using only its coordinates:

```
from turtle import *

t = Turtle()

def got(x,y,d) :        # to use goto more easily
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    t.seth(d)

x=0
y=0
d=0
megalist = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,]

for i in megalist :
    x = x + i
    y= y +4
    got(x,y,d)
    t.forward(-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would be possible for turtle to return the coordinates used to make it?

Yes.  There are some `*_poly()` methods, normally used to create custom cursors, that can be used to do what you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.penup()

turtle.seth(45)

turtle.begin_poly()
turtle.circle(100, 90)
turtle.circle(-100, 90)
turtle.end_poly()

polygon = turtle.get_poly()

print(polygon)

for point in polygon:
    turtle.goto(point)
    turtle.pendown()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
((0.00,0.00), (13.96,17.51), (23.68,37.68), (28.66,59.51), (28.66,81.91),
(23.68,103.74), (13.96,123.91), (0.00,141.42), (-13.96,158.93),
(-23.68,179.10), (-28.66,200.94), (-28.66,223.33), (-23.68,245.16),
(-13.96,265.34), (0.00,282.84))
>
```

**SCREEN OUTPUT**

[image]

> when you interrupt a circle(), (...) to draw something else,like a
>   straight line (...), the circle() angle is changed. And i can't think
>   a way to change it back.

My belief is you *can* interrupt `circle()` by looping through small extents, save the position and heading, do your drawing, and restore the position and heading before the next circle extent iteration.  Here's a simple example that just saves and restores the heading as the drawing itself puts back the position:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

turtle.setheading(45)

for extent in range(9):
    turtle.circle(100, 10)

    heading = turtle.heading()

    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.backward(10)

    turtle.setheading(heading)

for extent in range(9):
    turtle.circle(-100, 10)

    heading = turtle.heading()

    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.backward(10)

    turtle.setheading(heading)

screen.exitonclick()
```

**SCREEN OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Amanzing, you answered the both questions , thanks !! Both works